# Python bs4 - Find text from all lists

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have two functions that scrape numbers from a website. Neither get the desired output but they're close. I know I'm missing something obvious.

```
def getNums():
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.53'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    nums = soup.find_all('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'})
    return nums
```

Output:

```
<ul class="numbers">
<li class="result">11</li>
<li class="result">13</li>
<li class="result">14</li>
<li class="result">27</li>
<li class="result">40</li>
<li class="result">41</li>
<li class="addresult">23</li>
</ul>

...
```

This output would be fine, but I've been struggling to take the numbers from the ResultSet and put them into an array.

2nd function:

```
def getMainNums():
    headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36 Edg/88.0.705.53'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    numdict = {
    '0': soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'}).find_all('li')[0].text,
    '1': soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'}).find_all('li')[1].text,
    '2': soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'}).find_all('li')[2].text,
    '3': soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'}).find_all('li')[3].text,
    '4': soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'}).find_all('li')[4].text,
    '5': soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'}).find_all('li')[5].text,
    '6': soup.find('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'}).find_all('li')[6].text,
    }
    return numdict
```

This second function pulls the numbers from the first instance of the list, which I'm aware is what I'm asking it to do. I want to ask it to get them from every list - of which there are typically around 100 per page.

**Ideally, I'd use the second function on each individual list - or with the first function I'd separate the numbers from the ResultSet list output and place them into an array (or use .text like I have in the second function).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do all you need inside one function. I will show you example of two `<ul>`s.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<ul class="numbers">
    <li class="result">11</li>
    <li class="result">13</li>
    <li class="result">14</li>
    <li class="result">27</li>
    <li class="result">40</li>
    <li class="result">41</li>
    <li class="addresult">23</li>
</ul>
<ul class="numbers">
    <li class="result">1</li>
    <li class="result">20</li>
    <li class="result">31</li>
    <li class="result">07</li>
    <li class="result">50</li>
    <li class="result">19</li>
    <li class="addresult">23</li>
</ul>
'''

def getNums():
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html.parser')
    uls = soup.find_all('ul', {'class' : 'numbers'})

    num_dict = {}
    for count_of_uls, each_ul in enumerate(uls):
        each_dict = {}
        for count_of_lis, num in enumerate(each_ul.find_all('li', class_='result')):
            each_dict[str(count_of_lis)] = num.text

        num_dict[str(count_of_uls)] = each_dict

    return num_dict
```

All this code does is to iterate though `uls` list and then finds all `<li>` tags for each `ul` and adds its value into dictionary. Finally adding each dictionary for individual `ul`s to final `num_dict`. The result would look like this:

```
{'0': {'0': '11', '1': '13', '2': '14', '3': '27', '4': '40', '5': '41'},
 '1': {'0': '1', '1': '20', '2': '31', '3': '07', '4': '50', '5': '19'}}
```